# JavaScript calling show hide methods

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm a complete newbie to JavaScript trying to understand simple things....

Please look at complete code below. It's simple, show and hide.
I'm doing something wrong due to which it's not working.

http://jsbin.com/esokic/edit#javascript,html,live

Would appreciate any help..

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>
<meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type" />
<title>Close</title>
<SCRIPT type="text/javascript" src="jquery.all.min.js"></SCRIPT>

<style type="text/css">
.header-nav-outer {
    float: left;
}
.get-daily-alerts-outer {
    background: rgb(161, 8, 8); border-width: 0px 2px 2px; border-style: solid; border-color: rgb(0, 0, 0); padding: 2px 10px 20px 20px; border-radius: 0px 0px 8px 8px; width: 477px; height: 88px; display: none; position: absolute; z-index: 1000; -moz-border-radius: 0 0 8px 8px; -webkit-border-radius: 0 0 8px 8px;
}
span.close {
    background: url("/img/snapdeal/sprite/snapdeal.png?v=1") no-repeat -674px -748px; padding: 1px 0px 1px 16px; color: rgb(255, 255, 255); font-size: 10px; cursor: pointer;
}
.get-daily-alerts-head {
    color: rgb(224, 220, 220); padding-bottom: 10px; font-size: 19px; font-weight: bold;
}
.get-daily-alerts-head span {
    font-size: 13px; font-weight: normal;
}
.header-top-nav {
    background: url("/img/snapdeal/sprite/snapdeal-x.png?v=1") repeat-x left -73px; margin: 0px 0px 3px 170px; width: 592px; height: 32px; overflow: hidden;
}
.get-deal-alerts {
    background: url("/img/snapdeal/sprite/snapdeal.png?v=1") no-repeat -565px -803px rgb(161, 8, 8); padding: 3px 5px; width: 115px; color: rgb(255, 255, 255); font-size: 11px; float: left; cursor: pointer; -moz-border-radius: 0 0 5px 5px; -webkit-border-radius: 0 0 5px 5px;
}
.csupport-drop-outer {
    float: right;
}
.csupport-drop {
    width: 120px !important; display: block;
    text-align: left;
    color: #C7C5C5;
    font-size: 11px;
    font-weight: normal;
    cursor: pointer;
}
span.selected-city {
    background: url("/img/snapdeal/sprite/snapdeal.png?v=1") no-repeat right 3px; padding-right: 20px;
}
.cust-support-outer {
    margin: 0px; width: 121px; height: auto;
    background: rgb(255, 255, 255); border-width: 0px 2px 7px; border-style: solid; border-color: rgb(0, 0, 0); margin: 0px; padding: 5px 2px; position: absolute; z-index: 1000 !important; border-radius: 0px 0px 7px 7px; -moz-border-radius: 0 0 7px 7px; -webkit-border-radius: 0 0 7px 7px;

}

ul.cust-support {
    background: rgb(255, 255, 255); list-style: none; margin: 0px; padding: 0px; color: rgb(94, 94, 94); font-size: 12px;
}
ul.cust-support li {
    margin-top: 1px;
    margin-right: 5px;
    border-bottom-color: #888484;
    border-bottom-width: 1px;
    border-bottom-style: dotted;
}
ul.cust-support li a {
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0px 0px 1px;
    padding: 3px;
    color: #5E5E5E;
    font-size: 12px;
    display: block;
    cursor: pointer;
    _cursor: hand;
}
.active-drop-tab {
    background: rgb(255, 255, 255); border-width: 2px 2px 0px; border-style: solid; border-color: rgb(0, 0, 0); color: rgb(51, 176, 212); cursor: default; -moz-border-radius: 8px 8px 0 0; -webkit-border-radius: 8px 8px 0 0;
}

</style>
<script type="text/javascript">
this.init=function(){
    $(".csupport-drop").click(function(){
        $(".csupport-drop").addClass("active-drop-tab");
        $(".cust-support-outer").show();
        return false
    });
    $(".close").click(function(){
        $(".get-daily-alerts-outer").hide();
        return false
    });
    $(".get-deal-alerts").click(function(){
        $(".get-daily-alerts-outer").show();
        return false
    });
};
</script>
</head>

<body>
    <DIV class="header-nav-outer">
        <DIV class="get-daily-alerts-outer">
            <DIV align="right"><SPAN class="close">Close</SPAN></DIV>
            <DIV class="get-daily-alerts-head">Get The Best Deals <SPAN>Everyday in your 
            mailbox</SPAN></DIV>
        </DIV>
        <DIV class="header-top-nav">
            <DIV class="get-deal-alerts">Get daily deal alerts</DIV>
            <DIV class="csupport-drop-outer">
                <DIV class="csupport-drop"><SPAN class="selected-city">Customer 
                    Support</SPAN></DIV>
                <DIV class="cust-support-outer" style="display:none;">
                <UL class="cust-support">
                    <LI><A><SPAN id="orderStatus">Order Status</SPAN></A></LI>
                    <LI><A><SPAN id="voucherResend">Resend Voucher</SPAN></A></LI>
                    <LI><A href="http://www.snapdeal.com/info/contactus" target="_blank">Contact 
                        Us</A></LI></UL></DIV>
        </DIV>
    </DIV>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: add more details.. what's going wrong? In which instruction is the problem? Have you tried debugging it with Firebug?

Comment: I hate to discourage somebody from providing code with their question, but in this case you could've omitted all the CSS stuff (but left it in your jsbin demo), or at least put it at the bottom after the important JS bit that you're asking about. Instead, you should've put much more detail about the actual problem you're having, e.g., instead of "It's not working" how about "I expect this code to show and hide stuff when the element is clicked, but nothing happens and I get no errors in the console."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You never actually call `init()` so your click handlers are never being applied.

```
$(function() { init(); });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".csupport-drop").click(function() {
        $(this).addClass("active-drop-tab");
        $(".cust-support-outer").show();
    });
    $(".close").click(function(){
        $(".get-daily-alerts-outer").hide();
    });
    $(".get-deal-alerts").click(function(){
        $(".get-daily-alerts-outer").show();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is on this line:

```
this.init=function(){
```

What you want there instead of defining an `init` function is a document.ready handler, so

```
$(document).ready(function(){
```

and then at the end of the code block where you've got:

```
};
```

you need to close off the call to `ready(` that was opened above, so:

```
});
```

Or just leave your existing code as is and add a separate document.ready handler that calls your init function:

```
$(document).ready(init);

// OR, if you need to do other things in your document ready:
$(document).ready(function() {
   // other stuff here
   init();
   // other stuff here
}
```

Updated demo: http://jsbin.com/esokic/6/edit

Comment: Sincerely appreciate your explanation